# How to rewrite git history to combine commits?

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket

I've been trying to Google this but I think I have a special case and I'm not grasping if there's a way to do this.

I started a project in a `master` branch and when it was stable enough, it was duplicated to a `staging` branch. Not long after, I decided to create a `dev` branch from `master`. Now at this point, I was looking into a CI build service and was pounding away at code trying to make my `staging` branch build correctly. So now my staging branch is 31 commits ahead of my `dev` branch (oops) but it's worth noting that each branch is its own environment and I didn't ignore certain config files before doing this branching. So I have a few files that I'm not trying to overwrite, which is why I want to tell Git/Bitbucket something like "**Dev, Staging and Master are where they should be and we will track every commit from now on...forget the past.**" Is there a way to do this?

I looked into git rebase but it was confusing since I'm dealing with so many commits that are merged.

Screenshot from Bitbucket
[image]

Comment: You can't just forget the past in Git.  To do this, you would probably need to rewrite history.  You should show a branch diagram and then tell us how you want it to look.

Comment: Based on the screen shot, you treat `dev` branch as main branch, why do you specify `staging` branch to trigger CI build? And "**we will track every commit from now on...forget the past**", do you mean squash the commits (or remove the older commits) for all branches? So what do you mean **merge commits** as the title mentioned?

Comment: I changed the title to reflect what I meant. And yes, i would like dev to be the main branch for development purposes, like branching. I think squashing is what I mean. I wasn't aware of that. I don't necessarily have to remove the commits, but most of those commits are on one file, a config file trying to get it to work.

Comment: @MartavisP. Did you squash the commits successful?

Comment: Thank you guys for the feedback. My apologies, I got sidetracked finishing up another project. I'm moving back to the project with this issue so I'll be trying out squashing soon.

Answer (score 0):

**If there are few commits on branches**, you can use `git rebase -i --root` to squash commits on the branches.

**If there are large number of commit on branch**, you’d better use the below as below to squash commits:

Assume the commit history as below:

```
              S1---S2---…---S31  staging
             /
A---B---…---X  dev
             \
              P1---P2---P3---P4---P5  production
```

First squash part of commits on `staging` and `production` branches which are ahead of `dev` branch:

```
git checkout -b temp dev
git merge production --squash
git branch -f production
git checkout -B temp dev
git merge staging --squash
git branch -f staging
```

Now the commit history will be:

```
              S  staging, temp
             /
A---B---…---X  dev
             \
              P  production
```

If this is what you need, you can delete temp branch by `git branch -D temp` and then push to remote by `git push -f --all`.

If you still need to squash the commit for `dev`, `staging` and `production` branch, you can continue squash by below commands:

```
git checkout -B temp <commit id for A>
git merge production --squash
git branch -f production
git checkout -B temp <commit id for A>
git merge staging --squash
git branch -f staging
git checkout -B temp <commit id for A>
git merge dev --squash
git branch -f dev
git branch -D temp
git push -f --all
```

Now the commit history will be:

```
  S'  staging
 /
A---X'  dev
 \
  P'  production
```